# How do I configure localhost nginx to proxy https remote backend

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am developing a web UI frontend in JS, for a backend API that is now using HTTPS.  The following nginx config on my development machine was all I needed:

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  disable_symlinks off;

  server {
    disable_symlinks off;
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass                http://www.my-api.com;
    }

    location /some-path/ {
      disable_symlinks off;
      root /var/www;
      index index.html;
    }
  }

}
```

But now `www.my-api.com` is an https endpoint.

What adjustments do I need to make to my nginx config, in order to forward my localhost requests to the HTTPS backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the server section that works for me.
@Jay Achar got me close, and to be honest there are a few things I should try in
order to simplify the config.
I added the following lines:-

```
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

I also found that I had the proxied host name incorrect. In my case the `www.`
on the front was not right. I suspect that the host's certificate doesn't match
with `www` in there.  Perhaps just using @Jay Achar's answer with the correct
remote host name would be all one would need.

The `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` comes from my openssl. I figured it
would be suitable as client certificate to send to the proxied host.

The only other change I made to @Jay Achar's config was in the lines

```
  proxy_set_header Host              $proxy_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $upstream_addr;
```

Again, perhaps those changes were not necessary.

```
    server {
        disable_symlinks off;
        listen 8080;
        server_name pb.localhost;
        
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
        location /api {
            proxy_pass  https://my-api.com:443;

            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_http_version  1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host              $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $upstream_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        }

        location /some-path/ {
            disable_symlinks off;
            root /var/www;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The config below listens on localhost port 8080 and redirects to https://www.my-api.com. Since the API is accessible on port 443, it should include the SSL certification check.

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  disable_symlinks off;

  server {
    disable_symlinks off;
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass                https://www.my-api.com;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }

    location /some-path/ {
      disable_symlinks off;
      root /var/www;
      index index.html;
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Jay Achar.  Suggested config has not work though.  API requests ended in `502 bad gateway`.  I think the relevant bit of nginx log is ...

```
2020/11/03 08:16:15 [error] 2202#2202: *9 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Unknown error) 
while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pb.localhost, request: "GET /api/serviceD
ev.svc/SystemInfo?_=1604351774815 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<ip-addr>:443/api/serviceDev.svc/Syst
emInfo?_=1604351774815", host: "pb.localhost:8080", referrer: "http://pb.localhost:8080/some-path/app
/signin.html"

```